# PHP Review page for form data before processing them (e.g. email them)

Tags: php, forms, post, preview

I have HTML Form that sends only the filled forms to an email through PHP. Well I need to first send that info to a review page for customer to check with all the filled-in info, have them review and submit it again, and only then send that info to an email. How to do this?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.amaderica.com");
// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ravila@art.com');

$name = $_POST['Attention_To'];

// Set parameters of the email
$to = "ravila@art.com";
$subject = "Art Promo Items Ordered";
$from = " nostrowski@art.com";
$headers = "From: $from";

$message =
    "Order has been placed. Attn to: $name .\n" .
    "Items:\n";
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue)
{
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   $fieldName: $fieldValue\n";
}

// Mail function that sends the email.
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: thank-you.html');
?>
```

Some of the fields in my form are `silver_name_badges`, `coffee_mug`, `plastic_bag`, `paper_bag`, `candy`, `moist_towlette`, `notepad_and_pen`, `tuck_box`, `red_tie`, `cap`, `red_lanyard`, etc.

Comment: If you need to review the email, then you should store it to database, then after review send the email

Comment: You can save all data to Session, redirect user to review page, and show fields from your session. Or, use DB solution.

Comment: I'm noob but I won't being needing a DB solution. How would I use session to properly place the form data into a review page?

Comment: You can use session like this `session_start(); $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_POST;`

Comment: How would I organize that so that it would grap the filled in form only? could you please show an example?

Comment: Side note: Use of relative URLs in `Location` header was not standardized yet. So you should better use an absolute URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Review page

Make the form submit to a review page, instead of your send page (=your code from the question). Apart from rendering the review page itself (with all the data), put copy of the data to hidden form fields. Add *Email* submit button, which submits the data (effectively in the same format as the original form) to the send page.

Example:

```
<dl>
<?
if (!empty($_POST['plastic_bag']))
{
?>
    <dt>Plastic bag:</dt>
    <dd><?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['plastic_bag'])?></dd>
<?
}
if (!empty($_POST['paper_bag']))
{
?>
    <dt>Paper bag:</dt>
    <dd><?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['paper_bag'])?></dd>
<?
}
// and so forth for all fields 
?>
</dl>

<form action="your_mailing_script_from_your_question.php" method="post">
<?
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".htmlspecialchars($key).
         "\" value=\"".htmlspecialchars($value)."\"/>\n";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Email this"/>
</form>
```

### "Back" button

In HTML4, you cannot have two buttons on the same form submit the form to a different URL. So there are two options:

- Easier: Make two forms, each including all the hidden fields, and one button. Each form submits to a different URL, one to email and one back to the form.
- Keep one form that submits to, let's say the email URL, but the script there checks what button was pressed (you have to name the button and check `empty($_POST["button_name"])`). then it detects that "Back" button was pressed, it redirects the post back to the form URL.

In HTML5, you can have every button to submit to different URL. Check `formaction` attribute of `input` tag. I do not know, if you can afford to use HTML5. Check [support for the attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp) in browsers.

Of course, you have to modify the form script to fill in the form with data, submitted by "Back" button. E.g.:

```
<p>
<label for="plastic_bag">Plastic bag:</label>
<?
$value =
    !empty($_POST["plastic_bag"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["plastic_bag"]) : NULL;
?>
<input name="plastic_bag" id="plastic_bag" value="<?=$value?>"/>
</p>
```